# Why does this code gives out of bounds error?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, c++14, c++17

I have been trying to understand the out of bound error for the following code but I'm unable to figure out. The original problem is https://codeforces.com/contest/148/problem/A . I don't know why I am stuck and can you tell me how I can avoid similar type of errors.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int k,l,m,n,d,count=0;

    cin>>k>>l>>m>>n>>d;
    int arr[d]={0}; 

    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i){
      int k1=k*(i+1); k1--;
      int l1=l*(i+1); l1--;
      int m1=m*(i+1); m1--;
      int n1=n*(i+1); n1--;

      if(arr[k1]==0 && k1<d){
        arr[k1]=1; count++;
      }
      if(arr[l1]==0 && l1<d){
        arr[l1]=1; count++;
      }
      if(arr[m1]==0 && m1<d){
        arr[m1]=1; count++;
      }
      if(arr[n1]==0 && n1<d){
        arr[n1]=1; count++;
      }

    }

    cout<<count;


    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `if(arr[k1]==0 && k1<d)` If `k1 >= d`, it's a bit too late to check for that **after** you've already accessed the array out of bounds.

Comment: `int arr[d]={0}` -- This is not valid C++.  Use `std::vector<int> arr(d);`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Using vector<int>arr(d,0); was also giving error

Comment: Now that you changed to vector, use `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements.  Then it will pinpoint you to where the issue is occurring, as an `std::out_of_range` exception will be thrown.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I used vector.at() but the error was that I was writing the condition wrong as pointed by IgorTandetnik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the bounds first, in:

```
if(arr[k1]==0 && k1<d)
```

with:

```
if(k1<d && arr[k1]==0)
```

The second condition will not be tested if the first one is false. But the counterpart is not true. The first condition will always be tested.

Comment: Now, please try to remove your VLA usage, go with std:: vectors and use reserve if you plan to grow them with push_back.